# Authenticating by using some letters from the password

Tags: authentication, onlinebanking

How do banks authenticate users just by asking some letters of the password. Does is mean that hashes of those individual words are stored in the database, and if yes then would not it make it very vulnerable to break those passwords. Can you please give me some insight in how they do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter if they hash this information or not. This way of proceeding is totally unsafe and makes the system very weak. So, the way they do it is really the 'wrong' way.

Comment: but, i doubt their systems are weak. its a bank.

Comment: @Anush Then, they must be relying on some other methods, like using a secured communication like http. Or, they must only allow very small transactions via this system. In itself the method your are describing is weak, very weak, because it reduces the entropy of the secret. Banks do make errors. Attacks are common and sometimes, they only learn on their errors.

Comment: Typo: I meant https, not http.